# 1.9.3 Internal server error on account login

Tags: magento-1.9, login, customer-account, server-setup

Recently, after some reports of customers, I found a strange behavior.

These customers receive an internal server error page while accessing their account.

Sometimes the error occurs for each page of the site.

Investigating I found that these errors correspond to errors reported in the server's errror_log:

```
[Mon Jul 09 15:38:19 2018] [warn] [client ---.--.--.-- (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server
[Mon Jul 09 15:38:19 2018] [error] [client ---.--.--.--] Premature end of script headers: index.php
```

At first I was thinking about a bad server configuration, but I noticed that to solve the problem with the account it is necessary to open the account in question in the backend and save it without making any changes.

After this procedure it is possible to log in from the frontend without any problem, at least for a certain period.

When the error occurs on all pages of the site, it is sufficient, instead, to remove the "persistent_shopping_cart" cookie from the browser to restore normal operation.

It seems that the error is only found by users with products in the shopping cart

Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Comment: I have the same identical problem, open the account in question in the backend and save it without making any changes, solve the problem, but i keep receiving notice from my customers thet their account is not workin, and it is very frustating. Someone have a permanent solution to this issue?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/145082)

Comment: @Diego in my case the issue was caused by a custom tax module. This module use cart quote to update taxes and it created a conflict when price of item in cart was update.