# Magento 1.9.3 Customer Login Internal Server Error

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, error, login

After some reports of customers, I found a strange behavior.

These customers receive an internal server error page while accessing their account. I found that these errors in the server's errror_log:

```
End of script output before headers: index.php, referer: https://[my-domain]/customer/account/login/
```

To solve the problem with the account it is necessary to open the account in question in the backend and save it without making any changes.

After this procedure it is possible to log in from the frontend without any problem, at least for a while.

Has anyone else encountered this problem?

A similar behaviour was asked in this post, but the errors are a bit different, so i made another post.
[1.9.3 Internal server error on account login](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/232916/1-9-3-internal-server-error-on-account-login)

Comment: This errors seems linked to an error in your custom or third-party code. If you can, the next time you have this error, you could try to put breakpoints or die() at differents points of the code in the login process to see where you can reach. Then double check observers, and rewrite that could be responsible for this and isolate the code each time.  Also, you can check others logs, you say "server error_log" I don't know if this means Apache/Nginx or Magento, but check every logs and files relevants (All Magento ones and Apache/Nginx) this might show you a more helpful error message

Comment: Did you fixed this error?...I got this error for all form submissions...can u pls help me?